# google apps script Exception: Failed to retrieve form data. Please wait and try again

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Friends, I made a script to send an email to the user as soon as he answered the forum form,But I'm getting this error quite often:**Exception: Failed to retrieve form data. Please wait and try again. at unknown function**
it is giving error in the following line: `to:emailSolicitante.getResponse()`
In my searches I am not finding solutions. It looks like the problem is with google. Could someone help me?? This is my complete code:

```
var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
var respostas = formResponse.getItemResponses();
var emailSolicitante = respostas[0];
var planilha =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('151F6ry81nER7UjPhlnQor2XFI4beV9avwwSD-nTjoIY');
var sheet = planilha.getActiveSheet();
var guia = planilha.getSheetByName("sheet0");



function numprotocolo() {
  var ultimaLInha = guia.getLastRow();
  var maiorID = Math.max.apply(null, guia.getRange("L2:L").getValues());
  var id = maiorID + 1
  guia.getRange(ultimaLInha, 12).setValue(id);
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var logo = DriveApp.getFileById('1T2VLuChpMN23gC3uCDses3Evq-DIWfbC')
  var inlineImages = {};
  inlineImages[logo.getId()] = logo.getBlob();
  var body = "<b>*** E-mail automático *** </b>" +  "<br />Seu requerimento foi protocolado (<b>" + "Protocol Nº "+ sheet.getRange(row,12).getValue()  + "</b>)" + "<br />ASSUNTO: "+ sheet.getRange(row,6).getValue() + ".<br />" + "CPF/CNPJ n° " + sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue() + "<br /> <br />" + "<b>Prazo de resposta - 72 horas</b>" + "<br /> <br />"
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:emailSolicitante.getResponse(), 
    subject:"Protocol",
    body:"", 
    htmlBody: body, 
    inlineImages:inlineImages
    });
}
```

explaining the code a little, I need to send the protocol number. And number as follows, through a column following the numerical sequence (ex. 1, 2, 3.....)
The part of the code that does this automatic numbering is:

```
 var lastRow = tab.getLastRow();
   var biggestID = Math.max.apply(null, tab.getRange("L2:L").getValues());
   var id = biggestID + 1
   tab.getRange(lastLine, 12).setValue(id);
```

Comment: 1) please check the code that does the automatic numbering works as expected. Without looking the spreadsheet, it *might* happen that the range is not correct or an unhandled error occurred while setting the data in the variables.

Comment: 2) *without sending mails*, make some tests - in order to see if an error occurs. Use try/catch and handle the exceptions. Consider (*if possible*) share a sample spreadsheet with some same data.

Comment: Do you still get the same error? It seems that this was a temporary outage https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/274069395, there are multiple other reports as well but it seems that it is no longer happening: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191640&s=created_time:desc

Comment: We have many forms active using `FormApp.getActiveForm()` and all of them are returning that "try again"-error occasionally. It seems to be a current problem and hard to handle as the respond count is growing meanwhile, so the index is not usable for accessing the data later.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**
`to:emailSolicitante.getResponse()`

**Substitute**
`to:emailSolicitante`

---

The sequence of the script is:
1 - get all the responses (`var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();`)

2 - get the latest response (`var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];`)

3 - get all the item responses for the latest response (`var respostas = formResponse.getItemResponses();`)

4 - get the response for the *first item* on the form for the most recent submission (`var emailSolicitante = respostas[0];`)

So `emailSolicitante` is a variable that contains the email address of the respondent.